# JAVA gives me wrong Date Results on Several devices

Tags: java, android, date, getdate

I have a weird problem I used Java to get a current date but I am getting different results on several devices, on one correct & on another wrong.
Here is my code:

```
 public String getCurrentDate() {
     /// get date
     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
     dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"));
     Date date = new Date();
     System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); //2017-11-13 18:20:46 correct time is 11am
     return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

On the device that gives the wrong result I set automatic time zone use network-provided time zone & time of the device is correct.

Comment: What time zone shown when you set automatic time zone on device ?

Comment: Let's not use Date class after calendar most of the date class has been deprecated

Comment: `network-provided time zone` can be incorrect.

Comment: Could it be that your devices have a wrong time zone setting?

Comment: I agree with @Lokesh that we should consider no longer using the outdated `Date` class, but my recommendation differs: get [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) and start using [the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) known as JSR-310. BTW, the code in the question does not use any deprecated `Date` methods.

Comment: tnx for answers . I found out that my problem probably have no answer because if network-provided time zone cant be trusted and in this Conditions I will not have any way to find out is time correct or not . there is just one thing I can do is force user to give me location or sim tools

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this method to get current time from your device:

```
public String getCurrentDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    return date;
  }
```

This method will return current date as string.

Comment: Please explain, does this give a different result from the code in the question? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Are testing with real devices?

You can also try the Calendar Class that are from Android. for more info visit (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)

Check the Example bellow:

```
  Calendar current_time_cal = Calendar.getInstance();                                  
  current_time_cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"));
  int hours = current_time.get(Calendar.HOUR);
  int current_am_pm = current_time.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
  current_time_cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (hours == 0)? 12 : hours);
  current_time_cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, current_time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
  current_time_cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Current time: " + c.getTime());

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```